# jquery hover issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, fadeto

I want to use jquery to create a black fade on hover with text over the black on a horizontal, scalable scrolling images (see attached screenshots). At the minute the images  fade opacity instead of fading to black. Example can be seen here: http://deanpauley.co.uk/new/index.html
I am new to using jquery have completely confused myself on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The CSS is as follows:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
    background:#f5f5f5;
    border-bottom-left:25px;
    border-left-color:#F0EFF1;
    border-left-height:1000px;
    }

#border {
    position:fixed;
    width:37px;
    height:8000px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-top:0px;
    z-index:2000;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    }

#infoleft
    {   
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    left:25px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.14em;
    line-height:1.2em;
    display:block;
    }

#infoleft ul {
    height:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 14.5px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    }

#infoleft ul li { 
    display: inline; 
    padding: 10px;
    }


#inforight
    {   
    position:fixed;
    top:21px;
    right:23px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 14.5px;
    letter-spacing: 1pxem;
    }


#inforight ul {
    height:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.13em;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    }


#images {
    position:absolute;
    left:30px;
    bottom:35px;
    top:100px;
    width:25000px;
    padding-top:80px;
    min-height:500px;



}

img {
    padding:5px;
    height:90%;
}

img a:hover {
    color:black;
    opacity:1;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}

a:hover {
    color:#0080ff;
}

#showinfo {
    position:fixed;
    top:150px;
    left:35px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    font-size:15px;
    z-index:2000;
}

#showinfo a {
    color:#000;
}

#showinfo a:hover {
    color:#0080ff;
    cursor:pointer;
}


#projectInfo {
    position: fixed;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    top: 185px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 280px;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 20px 32px 32px 30px;
    height: 280px;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    line-height:1.4em;
    letter-spacing:0.13em;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Dean Pauley — Recent work</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script defer src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="showinfo">
<a href="#" id="showProjectInfo"><span id="showhide">[+]</span></a>
</div>
<div id="projectInfo" style="display: block; ">
            <p>News from Nowhere</p>                            
            <p>—</p>
            <p>A response to The Tyranny of Email by John Freeman exploring how the quality of the written word has deteriorated due to the faster methods of digital communication by contrasting it with that of a pre-digital era. The leather bound-book consists of over 3000 different spam emails.

</p>
</div>
<div id="border">
</div>
<div id="infoleft">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Dean Pauley</a></li>
<li>Graphic Design</li>
<li>mail@deanpauley.co.uk</li>
<li>+44(0)7969 652 219</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="inforight">
<ul>
<li><a href="info.html" class="transition">Information</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="images">
<a href="#"><img src="images/img_off.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/Calendar1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/img_off.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/Calendar1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/img_off.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/Calendar1.jpg" /></a>
<img src="images/NFN800.jpg" />
<img src="images/NFN800.jpg" />
<img src="images/NFN800.jpg" />
<img src="images/NFN800.jpg" />
<img src="images/NFN800.jpg" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").hover(function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({opacity: "0.8"}, '100');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({opacity: "1"}, '100');
    });
  });
</script>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("projectinfo").hide();
        $("showprojectinfo").show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $("projectinfo").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
<script src="js/script.min.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Screenshots:

[image: image on hover]

EditIt now works @Duopixel but it now has a black border.
See attached screen shot. How can I get rid of this?

[image]

"Edit"

Answer (score 1):

Add...

```
#images a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  margin-right: 3px /*adjust to your linking*/
}

#images img {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Then adjust the opacity in jQuery to whatever looks good to you.

Comment: Yes! this is working fine.. @Duopixel, I have used gravatar for sample on http://jsfiddle.net/m7a8r/  check this out it works

Comment: But how can I get rid of the black border that now appears?

Comment: Are you sure you added `#images img {...}` in your CSS?

Comment: @Duopixel The CSS looks like: 
#images {
 position:absolute;
 left:30px;
 bottom:35px;
 top:100px;
 width:25000px;
 padding-top:80px;
 min-height:500px;
 


}

img {
 padding:5px;
 height:90%;
}

#images a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  margin-right: 3px;
  /*adjust to your linking*/
}

#images img {
  pading: 0;
}

img a:hover {
 color:black;
 opacity:1;
}

Comment: Problem solved, missed out a "d" in padding from copying the above. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @duopixel Sorry, just realised another problem. The Hover works but now the images no longer scale along with the browser window. Do you know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

What i found from your code is you are missing '#' & '.' prefix in jQuery code, below is the correction:

```
$("#projectinfo").hide();
```

or

```
$(".projectinfo").hide();
```

Please note that '#' is used as prefix with IDs and '.' is used as prefix with classes. Hence, if projectinfo is name of cssClass then second option would be helpful:

Hope this Helps.